# ¿Hay alguna diferencia entre "View v" y "View view" en Android?

Tags: java, android

Cuando hago los métodos para cambiar entre pantallas:

```
public void nombreMetodo (View v){ 
   Intent uno = new Intent (this, nombreJava.class); 
   startActivity (uno); 
}
```

Siempre que hago lo de `"public void nombreMetodo (View v)"` al escribir lo de `View` doy espacio y me sugiere `view` en minúsculas. Entonces tengo duda sobre si hay problema en usar la pura `"v"` como acostumbro o es mejor usar `"view"`.

Código de Android Studio

```
 public void reg (View view){
      Intent pa = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(pa);
  }
```

Comment: Solo es por convención de nombres. Se puede llamar de cualquier forma , lo importante es el tipo de la variable , en este caso `View`

Comment: Como dice el compañero son variables el nombre en si mismo (v o view) no es importante, puedes poner lo que quieras, el importante es el tipo (View)

Comment: Muchas gracias por aclarar mi duda. Buen día

Answer (score 2):

No existe ninguna diferencia, ùnicamente indicas el nombre de la variable de este tipo puede ser `v`, `view` o cualquier otro nombre, por ejemplo `rootView`:

```
public void nombreMetodo(View rootView){ 
   ...
   ...
}
```

incluso en el SDK puedes encontrar métodos con nombres de variable diferente como `drawerView`:

```
   @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
    }
```

Recuerda que por convencion de Java, los nombres de variable inician con minuscula.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario Jorge, te lo agradezco.

Answer (score 0):

No hay diferencia entre una y otra, es decir tal como dicen los demas, lo importante es el tipo de variable, en tu caso View, lo que vaya despues es el nombre que le pones, por ejemplo oPuedoAtizarteEnLaCaraYdejarteSecoEnElSuelo, seria un nombre aceptable porque no tiene ninguna palabra reservada ni ningun signo que le impida ser el nombre de variable, podria ser menos brusco, Sí, quiero que lo sea, No.